# Error with persist Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to create a register handler. I have a `User` entity and Register.php. Register.php extends `User`, registers set hashing password  and returns results.

[Code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a3abb3159ff6a5696b0d):

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createTestForm(new User);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $service  = new Register($form->getData());
        $register = $service->register();
        $em->persist($register);
        $em->flush();
        // return $this->redirectToRoute(...);
    }
    return $this->render('AcmeExampleBundle:User:test.html.twig', array(
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I get this error: `The class 'Acme\ExampleBundle\Libs\Register' was not found in the chain configured namespaces AcmeExample\Bundle\Entity`

Comment: I don't think that you should extend User entity for this. Why don't you do password hashing in User entity? If you want to have some "handler", best solution would be to create service.

Comment: Ok, i created service. I pass data to serivce, service doing hash password and return result. How to save a changed password from service to the database?